# Que significan las llaves en una consulta con WHERE id = {$id}?

Tags: php, sql

Acabo de ver esta consulta en php:

```
return $conn->query("SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = {$id}");
```

¿que significa las llaves en {$id} ? ¿es algun tipo de referencia por ser una variable?

Comment: estas usando algun framework ?

Comment: no, no estoy usando ninguno. Solo php.

Comment: en ese caso puede ser debido al coding style o para aprovechar el coloreado del editor y que no se pierda la referencia de la variable dentro del string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La sintáxis que expresas en tu pregunta es otra manera de pasar una variable a una declaración

Me explico

Esto es válido:

```
return $conn->query("SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = $id");
```

Sin embargo como sabemos dentro de una declaración de comillas dobles podemos pasar variables; entonces lo que hacemos en meterla dentro de la sintáxis de llaves para que ese valor se asuma como dinámico, es decir que puede cambiar y no que lo tome como una simple cadena de texto

Esto también es válido

```
return $conn->query("SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = {$id}");
```

Por que en otro tipo de declaraciones vas a encontrar esta sintáxis también

`return $conn->query("SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = '".$id."' ");`

> Lo anterior también es válido con fines funcionales y lo único que le
>   estamos indicando es que estamos concatenando por dentro de la
>   declaración un valor que es dinámico; para que nuevamente sea
>   diferenciado del resto de la declaración y se asuma como una variable
>   y no como una simple cadena de texto

Comment: si no se usan índices tal vez un ejemplo mas visible es `$var = "cosa"; echo "hay muchas $vars";` <- `error no existe $vars` en cambio `$var = "cosa"; echo "hay muchas {$var}s";` imprime "hay muchas cosas"

Comment: Entiendo que funciona para variables dinamicas como es el caso pero ¿que podria fallar si no se ponen las llaves? ¿Por que es tan necesario su uso?

Comment: @RicardoKra su uso es netamente opcional por eso te puse otros ejemplos y se colocan las llaves para que puedas meter a la variable dentro de las comillas dobles y evites tener que concatenar valores

Comment: Aprovecho para preguntar, trae consigo alguna penalización al rendimiento la inclusión de la variable dentro de  cadena??

Comment: @Francisco no, el redimiento de tu query, depende en si mismo de la lógica y lo bien estructurada que este esta misma

Comment: @Alfredo Ok!!!!

Answer (score 2):

esa sintaxis la puedes utilizar cuando agregas el valor de una posición de un array ejemplo:

```
$id = explode ('|', 'algo|juan'); 

mysql_query("SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id ='{$id[1]}'");   
echo "SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id ='{$id[1]}'"; 

//SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id ='juan'
```

Las llaves “{}” Tambien indica que es obligatorio poner lo que hay dentro,
pero al ver tu consulta tan simple, no creo que sea necesario tenerlo

Comment: el {$id} se pasa por referencia en la siguiente funcion:
function obtenerNombreProyecto($id = null){
  include 'conexion.php';
  try{
   return $conn->query("SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = $id"); //las llaves permiten inyectar el $id
  } catch(Exception $e) {
   echo "Error! : " . $e->getMessage();
   return false;
  }
 }
esta funcion se llama en otro archivo y el id se toma de un parametro que viene por  url.
Por probar he quitado las llaves y veo que funciona igual. En el tuto que veo esto indica que se pone asi para inyectar la variable id. ¿Pensais que es necesario?

Comment: A grandes rasgos, creo que no es necesario, ya que usualmente el id siempre sera unico (a menos que ese id pueda ser dinamico)